# Clojure join multiple table

Tags: clojure, honeysql

I am trying to solve the query in clojure. It has to return only one row. But it is returning multiple row. The function is picking the correct row from Customer table, but along with that it is fetching all the 3 row from queue table and all 4 row from service table. So totally I am getting 12 (1X3X4) row instead of only one. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks.

```
SELECT a.first_name, b.queue_name, c.service_name 
from customer a
  JOIN queue b
    on a.queue_id = b.queue_id
  JOIN service c
    on a.service_id = c.service_id
where a.empl_id = 'BA123';

(defn query-using-map
  "Generates a query using a honey sql map and returns the results"
  [query-map]
  (jdbc/with-db-transaction [conn {:datasource config/datasource}]
   (let [sql-query (sql/format query-map)
          query-result (jdbc/query conn sql-query)]
       query-result)))

(defn get-servicename-queuename [emplid]
 (jdbc/with-db-transaction [conn {:datasource config/datasource}]
 (let [result (query-using-map 
   {:select [:a.first_name :b.queue_name :c.service_name]
    :from [[:customer :a] [:queue :b] [:service :c]]
    :join [":a.queue_id=:b.queue_id and :a.service_id=:c.service_id"]
    ; OR :join [[:= :a.queue_id :b.queue_id] [:= :a.service_id :c.service_id]]
    :where [:= :a.empl_id emplid]})](println result))))

;(get-servicename-queuename "BA123")
```

Comment: the join condition being a string of keywordized things does not look right, and the comment below it has two conditions but they are not together in an and. what is `query-using-map`, are you using a DSL? Please include the flavor if so.

Comment: I bet if you put the joins in the where clause it would work, probably your DSL doesn't support :join as a thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the code snippet for query-using-map. I am following the honeysql documentation "https://github.com/jkk/honeysql". I hope I cannot place the join in the where clause by this documentation.

Comment: I see. According to the HoneySQL documentation the syntax should be `:join [:draq [:= :f.b :draq.x]]`

Comment: I tried that way as well by replacing the queue instead of draq